# Pronunciation of the word stereotype

Tags: pronunciation

Should the word "stereotype" sounds like /ˈster.i.ə.taɪp/ like in the dictionary, instead of "stereo"+"type" which is the way I felt most peoples are pronouncing with? If so, is there any meaning for the silence O?

Comment: Did you look up the pronunciation in a dictionary? If so, what did it tell you?

Comment: The symbols printed out appear to be the "pronunciation" from a dictionary. American dictionaries don't use standard pronunciation symbols, since they think Americans are too ignorant to understand IPA. As far as the question goes, those are the same pronunciations -- they just aren't clear from the dictionary. Don't bother with pronunciations copied from American dictionaries. If you want the American pronunciation, use [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse). Or use the English-X part of a bilingual dictionary -- the pronunciations there will be phonemic.

Comment: @johnlawler Just replaced the pronunciation I found directly from google to where I found on Cambridge dictionary. It should be better now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the "silent O", as the pronunciation clearly includes the "schwa" sound for that syllable... since it's unstressed, the sound tends toward "uh", so most people will say "Stare-ee-uh-type".

Comment: Apart from what Hellion said, Lexico gives /-ə(ʊ)-/ which means it could be pronounced both ways i.e. the O can either be pronounced as schwa or /əʊ/ (AmE: /oʊ/)

Comment: The "word" **stereo** ends with dipthong **əʊ** in the full OED, but ALL their phonetic representations for **stereotype** (**/ˈstɛrɪə(ʊ)tʌɪp/, /ˈstɪərɪə(ʊ)tʌɪp/, /ˈstɛriəˌtaɪp/**) are the same as for **photograph** (**/ˈfəʊtəɡrɑːf/, /ˈfəʊtəɡraf/, /ˈfoʊdəˌɡræf/**), in that the second syllable is a schwa. Only people who are being misled by the spelling would be likely to "hypercorrect" that schwa into the diphthong form from the shorter word.

Comment: I say 'sterayotype'.

Comment: I think I pronounce the O, but it's the least stressed of all the syllables, so it's easy for it to devolve into a schwa.